# Send-tip to pooltool.io

Tags: stake-pool

I am trying to send tip info to pooltool.io.

I have already created an account on pooltool.io site and transferred the 1.056 Ada from my stake pool's wallet and I have access to the "manage" tab for my pool.  I have the apiKey and poolId.

When I submit the json data to pooltool.io I get an error response.

This is my bash command used to send the tip information:

```
RESPONSE="$(curl -s -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST --data "$JSON" 'https://api.pooltool.io/v0/sendstats')"
```

This is the contents of the `$JSON` variable:

```
{
  "apiKey": "xxxxxxxx-modified for privacy-xxxxxxxx",
  "poolId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "data": {
    "nodeId": "",
    "version": "1.30.1:0fb43",
    "at": "2021-10-21T14:20:38.46Z",
    "blockNo": "6399612",
    "slotNo": "43259747",
    "blockHash": "641da85f02d37759fa6bb7e2e9691c2a06728baa2441706c997bc894d276420e",
    "platform": "send-tip"
  }
}
```

And here is the `$RESPONSE` value returned:

```
{"success":false,"dev":true,"message":"Unknown API ID"}
```

I can't see what the problem is.  Any ideas?

Has there been any change to the web address to send to?

Comment: By the way, I do have the correct values for poolId and apiKey.

Comment: I can not see anything wrong there. I'd suggest you open an issue on Github and see what they say: https://github.com/papacarp/pooltool.io/issues

Comment: It seems that the problem has now resolved itself.  Maybe pooltool.io changed something to activate my apiKey???.  With the exact same code, I am now getting $RESPONSE:
{"success":true,"dev":true,"message":null}

Comment: great! thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a problem on PoolTool recently and some keys had to be reactivated manually by the operators. I'm sure they probably sorted out yours as well!